# Ruby on Rails: Active-Record sort and put specific row to the top

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord

I have an Active record `one -> many` association and I need to `get all child rows` **starting with a specific row**

something like

`parent.children.startwith(some_child_row_id)`

Is there a one-liner?

**Edit:** 
For more Clarity

Let say we have an array

```
a = ["a","b" ,"cg", "d","e"]
```

I want `"cg"` to be first element.
I'll do somthing like

```
element = a.delete("cg")  // array will be ["a","b","d","e"]
a.unshift(element) // array will now become ["cg","a","b","d","e"]
```

See! An element is moved to index 0.

**I want the same in case of ActiveRecord rows**, Preferably a One-liner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose conditional ordering will do the trick.

```
parent.children.order("CASE WHEN (id = #{some_child_row_id}) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ASC, id")
```

Comment: I want to get ``all`` child rows starting with a specific one.

Comment: Be more specific. All rows that are children of a specific parent? Or all rows that have a parent?

Comment: All rows that are children of a ``specific`` parent.

Comment: Please review the question. I have added an example.

Comment: Yes, I figured out what you meant earlier, that's why I edited my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty simple actually.

All you need is to apply a where clause to the children of your parent.

Try something like this.

```
parent.children.where('id > ?', start_row)
```

I believe this is what you were looking for. Hope this helps.

Comment: Actually, I want collection of all child rows of a parent in return, starting from a specific row.

Comment: @WaqarHassan How is the specific row defined? Is it based on id or soemthing else?

Comment: It is based on id from one of child rows.

Comment: What's the problem with `parent.children.where('id > 10')`? It will give you all the children of parent having id greater than 10.

Comment: Please review the question. I have added an example.